# How to swap between two different layout with animation in android

Tags: java, android, animation

I have two different layouts in my android app , i have tried to swap between them but animation is not slow and it is not working properly , can anyone please suggest me a better way to switch between both layout , i have layout with width of 60 dp and when clicked it expands to match_parent with slow animation , this is what i have tried so far .

- First Layout

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorCollapsedLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomLayoutMini"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:gravity="bottom">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tickIcon"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_done_24"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:tint="#FF5722" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

- Second Layout

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorExpandedLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomLayoutExpanded"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:gravity="bottom">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bigTick"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_done_24"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:tint="#FF5722" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/allLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/smallTick"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_done_24"
                        app:tint="#FF5722" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
                        android:text="@string/game_booster"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="11sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
                        android:text="Active"
                        android:textColor="#B53030"
                        android:textSize="11sp" />

                    <Space
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/pinImage"
                        android:layout_width="15dp"
                        android:layout_height="15dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_push_pin_24" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/pingJitterLayout"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/pingJitterLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/fps"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
                            android:text="@string/fps_ms"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="11sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/ping"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
                            android:text="@string/ping_ms"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="11sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/jitter"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
                            android:text="@string/jitter_ms"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="11sp" />


                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

- Activity code

```
 sceneRootFrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.sceneRootFrameLayout);
        // Step 1: Create a Scene object for both the starting and ending layout
        scene1 = Scene.getSceneForLayout(sceneRootFrameLayout, R.layout.collapsed_layout_portrait, this);
        scene2 = Scene.getSceneForLayout(sceneRootFrameLayout, R.layout.expanded_layout_portrait, this);

        scene1.enter();
        currentScene = scene1;


        transition = TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.example1);

        sceneRootFrameLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (currentScene == scene1) {
                    TransitionManager.go(scene2, transition);
                    currentScene = scene2;
                } else {
                    TransitionManager.go(scene1, transition);
                    currentScene = scene1;
                }
            }
        });
```

- transition file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<changeBounds xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:transitionOrdering="sequential"
    android:duration="4000"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/linear">
</changeBounds>
```